# toggle div if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="parent1" class="article">
   <div class="action"></div>
   <div id="exp1" class="expand"></div>
</div>
<div id="parent2" class="article">
   <div class="action"></div>
   <div id="exp2" class="expand"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.article:hover .action {
   z-index:1000;
}
.expand {
   display: none;
} 
action {
   background: url(../images/down.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
   z-index: -999;
}
.collapse {
   background: url(../images/up.png) 0 0 no-repeat !important;
   z-index: 1000;
}
```

and Javascript:

```
$(".article").click(function() {
   $(this).find(".action").toggleClass("collapse"); // works onclick div article
   ????????? // when press parent1 if parent2 pressed before ???????.find(".action").toggleClass("collapse");
   $("#exp2").hide(); // if previously open
   $("#exp1").toggle(300);
}
```

Now I need jQuery for onclick parent1 to toggleClass action in parent2 but only if prevously toggled to collapse.

Comment: For one, `z-index=1000;` is not valid CSS; it should be: `z-index: 1000;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it. Normally I would store a local variable that holds the state of the drop down (boolean) and just check that.

With jQuery, since you are already using hide(), you can use:

```
if ($("#exp2").is(":hidden")) {
    // Show content, set arrow to up.
    $("#exp2").removeClass("expand").addClass("collapse");
}
else {
    // Hide content, set arrow to down.
    $("#exp2").removeClass("collapse").addClass("expand");
}
```

The toggle would make more sense if you were just adding and removing a class. Here you are alternating classes. Using addClass() and removeClass() makes it very clear what you are doing.

Comment: How do i call this function onclick parent1 for parent2 $(#parent2).find(".action").toggleClass("collapse"); is not working

Comment: I understand what you are asking, but that is really just going to make it more confusing. If it's alternating, you can handle it all in one method called by both onclick events. I know what jQuery was intending, but I think the functionality is a bit lofty. If you use the single method approach (with a common variable such as  $("#exp2").is(":hidden"), you can get the results you need.

Comment: I did something like this       <script type="text/javascript" >
        $("#art21").click(function() { 
        if (!($("#exp22").is(":hidden")) && ($("#exp21").is(":hidden"))) {
              $("#exp22").hide();
              $("#art22").find(".action").toggleClass("collapse");
       } 
          $("#exp21").toggle(300);}

Comment: Are you all set then? if you are, then the answer was to use the .is(":hidden") property of the element in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I take a guess here but I think you want to close any open .article and open the one you clicked on.

```
$(".article").click(function() {
   // see explanations 1 and 2 below
   $('.article.active').removeClass('active').find('#exp1').hide();

   // see explanation 3 below
   $(this).addClass('active').find('#exp2').show();
}
```

You can change the code to suit your need but so you understand it:

1. When we click on an .article, we look for any other .article with a specific class (.active in my exemple). Technically, there will likely be only one of .article.active
2. We remove its .active class and do whatever on it or its child
3. We finally do whatever on the clicked article